# replace img tag with alt using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use Regex, but used it only in PHP and years ago:

```
var msgText = thisMSG.getElementsByClassName('message-text')[0].getElementsByClassName('emojitext')[0].innerHTML;
msgText = msgText.replace('/<img src="([\.]*)"([\.]*)alt="[([\.]*)">/g','\\3');
```

I want to replace the img tag with the alt content:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" class="emoji emojiordered0186 selectable-text" draggable="false" alt="❤">
```

any idea what wrong?

edit: the image can be a part of a sentnce, like:

```
I <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" class="emoji emojiordered0186 selectable-text" draggable="false" alt="❤"> U!
```

Comment: are you sure you have to use regex for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use regex for that. Use the code below, instead.

```
var msgText = thisMSG.querySelector(".message-text .emojitext");
msgText.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(msgText.alt), msgText);
```

For multiple changes:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".message-text .emojitext"), function(emoji) {
   emoji.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(emoji.alt), emoji);
});
```

Comment: But if the image it's just a part of other text? like:      I <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" class="emoji emojiordered0186 selectable-text" draggable="false" alt="❤"> u!

Comment: What do you mean by "image it's just part of other text"?

Comment: the image is not the whole string, can be more text before and after

Comment: It doesn't matter. The code replaces only the image. Just provide the proper selector for the img tag and you are done. 
In the code you posted, it would be ".message-text .emoji"

Comment: It must work, maybe just do document.querySelector(".emoji"), you must try playing with selectors.

Comment: yea, got it too (another answer here)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it:

```
var msgText = null;
while ( msgText = thisMSG.querySelector('.message-text .emojitext .emoji') )
{
  msgText.outerHTML = msgText.alt;
}
```

and for use the text:

```
thisMSG.querySelector('.message-text .emojitext').innerHTML
```

Comment: This is in effect what Jakub Rożek was suggesting. It would have been fair to accept his answer as the accepted and add this as a comment or an edit. Considering it was a little ambiguous what you were asking for.

Comment: you are right.. still trying to get how this site work. anyway I won't delete my comment, maybe it will help to someone else.